# Unity3D: When used with builtin render pipeline, Postprocessing package expects to be used on a fullscreen Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing, unity3d-editor

I'm using the Universal Render Pipeline and I've added some post-processing. Everything works fine, I have no issues with the build or testing. Although I'm using a single Camera, whenever I click anywhere in the Scene view (no matter if I select a GameObject or not), I get the following warning in the console:

> When used with builtin render pipeline, Postprocessing package expects
>   to be used on a fullscreen Camera. Please note that using Camera
>   viewport may result in visual artefacts or some things not working.
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:187)

Can someone please explain what does this mean and how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the post processing script with the main camera?

Comment: I was just making a silly mistake. After some changes the URP asset was not assigned in Project Settings->Graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that after making some changes, the URP asset was no longer assigned in Project Settings->Graphics.

That was all, it doesn't throw the warning anymore.